# Add existing mongo db property value to a number in an update many

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update documents that fall between two points in mongodb:

```
 PaginatedArticlePage
        .find({ article: req.params.articleId })
        .bulkWrite([
            {
                updateMany: {
                    filter: {
                        $and: [
                            { page_number: { $lte: endpage } },
                            { page_number: { $gte: startPage } },
                            { page_number: { $ne: startPage } }
                        ]
                    },
                    update: { $set: { $add: [ $page_number, - 1] } }
                }
            },
            {
                updateMany: {
                    filter: { page_number: { $eq: startPage } },
                    update: { $set: { page_number: endpage } }
                }
            }
        ])
```

When I execute this, I get an error of:
`ReferenceError: $page_number is not defined`

I'm trying to add the existing `$page_number` to a -1.

Why is `$page_number` coming back as undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few reasons why this isn't working. When you use `$page_number` it's getting interpreted as a variable. You would need to wrap it in quotes, but doing that won't help because of the operator you chose.

You use the [$add](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) operator which is only for use in an aggregation pipeline. It only returns the result of the addition, and will not perform an update.

In your case it would be more appropriate to use the [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operator. With the `$inc` operator your update document would look like this:

```
update: { $inc: { page_number: -1 } }
```

Comment: I'm seeing a weird behavior with the update; for the first document, it  subrtracts like it should, but for the second document, it subtracts nothing; am i missing something with how `$inc` works?

Comment: i figured out the issue. after incrementing, the updated value catches on the next filter; thanks for your help. your answer is what i needed!